# TLV implementation in C++

Tags: c++, serialization

I tried implementing TLV(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value).
Actually my implementation is more than TLV because it supports additional "Tag" elements (which you can use for naming certain TLV objects) for TLV objects.
My goal is to serialize the array of TLV objects to byte array and vice versa (this I didn't implement yet).
But I wrote class which handles single TLV and their serialization/deserialization. If this class is OK I believe it is much easier to extend it to arrays.
Here is implementation. Feel free to comment.

Btw:

- the class assumes little endian encoding for integers
- and no unicode strings are supported

PS. So basically single TLV object is a data structure which can either hold: a numeric type, string, or byte array, a type variable indicating which type of data it is, and a tag name indicating what value it is e.g. "phone number".

.cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TLVObject.h"


TLVObject::TLVObject(void)
{
    clearMembers();
}

TLVObject::~TLVObject(void)
{
}

//////////////////////////////////////
// Integers to byte arrays

vector<uint8_t> TLVObject::UINT16ToByteArrayLE(uint16_t paramInt)
{

    vector<uint8_t> arrayOfByte(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        arrayOfByte[i] = ((paramInt >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF);
    return arrayOfByte;

}


vector<uint8_t> TLVObject::UINT32ToByteArrayLE(uint32_t paramInt)
{
    vector<uint8_t> arrayOfByte(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        arrayOfByte[i] = ((paramInt >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF);
    return arrayOfByte;
}


vector<uint8_t> TLVObject::UINT64ToByteArrayLE(uint64_t paramInt)
{
    vector<uint8_t> arrayOfByte(8);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        arrayOfByte[i] = ((paramInt >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF);
    return arrayOfByte;

}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Byte array to integers

uint16_t TLVObject::LEToUINT16(vector<uint8_t> value)
{
    if(value.size() != 2)
        throw exception("LEToUINT16: Wrong size");

    return (uint16_t)(((uint16_t)value[1] << 8) | (uint16_t)value[0]);
}

uint32_t TLVObject::LEToUINT32(vector<uint8_t> value)
{
    if(value.size() != 4)
        throw exception("LEToUINT32: Wrong size");

    return (uint32_t)(((uint32_t)value[3] << 24) | ((uint32_t)value[2] << 16) | ((uint32_t)value[1] << 8) | (uint32_t)value[0]);    
}

uint64_t TLVObject::LEToUINT64(vector<uint8_t> value)
{
    if(value.size() != 8)
        throw exception("LEToUINT64: Wrong size");

    uint64_t result =  static_cast<uint64_t>(value[0]) |
        static_cast<uint64_t>(value[1]) << 8 |
        static_cast<uint64_t>(value[2]) << 16 |
        static_cast<uint64_t>(value[3]) << 24 |
        static_cast<uint64_t>(value[4]) << 32 |
        static_cast<uint64_t>(value[5]) << 40 |
        static_cast<uint64_t>(value[6]) << 48 |
        static_cast<uint64_t>(value[7]) << 56;

    return result;
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////
// Serialization and Deserialization methods

vector<uint8_t> TLVObject::Serialize()
{
    vector<uint8_t> tmp;

    // Serialize type first
    tmp.push_back((uint8_t)m_tlvType);

    // Serialize tag name length (which is 2 bytes max) as little endian byte array
    uint16_t tagLen = (uint16_t)m_tagName.length();
    tmp.push_back(UINT16ToByteArrayLE(tagLen).at(0));
    tmp.push_back(UINT16ToByteArrayLE(tagLen).at(1));

    // Now serialize tag name itself
    for(int i = 0; i < tagLen; i++)
    {
        tmp.push_back((uint8_t)m_tagName.at(i));
    }

    // Data size 4 byte integer.
    uint32_t dataSize = 0;

    if(m_tlvType == BLOB)
    {
        dataSize = m_blob.size();

        // Serialize size
        vector<uint8_t> tmp1 = UINT32ToByteArrayLE(dataSize);
        tmp.push_back(tmp1.at(0));
        tmp.push_back(tmp1.at(1));
        tmp.push_back(tmp1.at(2));
        tmp.push_back(tmp1.at(3));

        // Now, serialize the blob.
        for(uint32_t i = 0; i<dataSize; i++)
            tmp.push_back(m_blob[i]);

    }else if(m_tlvType == STRING)
    {
        dataSize = m_strValue.length();

        // Serialize size
        vector<uint8_t> tmp1 = UINT32ToByteArrayLE(dataSize);
        tmp.push_back(tmp1.at(0));
        tmp.push_back(tmp1.at(1));
        tmp.push_back(tmp1.at(2));
        tmp.push_back(tmp1.at(3));

        // Now, serialize the string.
        for(uint32_t i = 0; i<dataSize; i++)
            tmp.push_back(m_strValue[i]);

    }else if(m_tlvType == BYTE)
    {
        dataSize = 1;

        // Serialize size
        vector<uint8_t> tmp1 = UINT32ToByteArrayLE(dataSize);
        tmp.push_back(tmp1.at(0));
        tmp.push_back(tmp1.at(1));
        tmp.push_back(tmp1.at(2));
        tmp.push_back(tmp1.at(3));

        // Serialize the byte.
        tmp.push_back(m_BYTE);

    }else if(m_tlvType == WORD)
    {
        dataSize = 2;

        // Serialize size
        vector<uint8_t> tmp1 = UINT32ToByteArrayLE(dataSize);
        tmp.push_back(tmp1.at(0));
        tmp.push_back(tmp1.at(1));
        tmp.push_back(tmp1.at(2));
        tmp.push_back(tmp1.at(3));

        // Now, serialize the WORD value.
        tmp.push_back(UINT16ToByteArrayLE(m_WORD).at(0));
        tmp.push_back(UINT16ToByteArrayLE(m_WORD).at(1));

    }else if(m_tlvType == DWORD)
    {
        dataSize = 4;

        // Serialize size
        vector<uint8_t> tmp1 = UINT32ToByteArrayLE(dataSize);
        tmp.push_back(tmp1.at(0));
        tmp.push_back(tmp1.at(1));
        tmp.push_back(tmp1.at(2));
        tmp.push_back(tmp1.at(3));

        // Now, serialize the unsigned integer.
        vector<uint8_t> tmp2 = UINT32ToByteArrayLE(m_DWORD);
        tmp.push_back(tmp2.at(0));
        tmp.push_back(tmp2.at(1));
        tmp.push_back(tmp2.at(2));
        tmp.push_back(tmp2.at(3));

    }else if(m_tlvType == QWORD)
    {
        dataSize = 8;

        // Serialize size
        vector<uint8_t> tmp1 = UINT32ToByteArrayLE(dataSize);
        tmp.push_back(tmp1.at(0));
        tmp.push_back(tmp1.at(1));
        tmp.push_back(tmp1.at(2));
        tmp.push_back(tmp1.at(3));

        // Serialize data
        vector<uint8_t> tmp2 = UINT64ToByteArrayLE(m_QWORD);
        tmp.push_back(tmp2.at(0));
        tmp.push_back(tmp2.at(1));
        tmp.push_back(tmp2.at(2));
        tmp.push_back(tmp2.at(3));
        tmp.push_back(tmp2.at(4));
        tmp.push_back(tmp2.at(5));
        tmp.push_back(tmp2.at(6));
        tmp.push_back(tmp2.at(7));
    }



    return tmp;
}

void  TLVObject::Deserialize(vector<uint8_t> value)
{
    // Get type
    TLV_TYPE tlvType =  static_cast<TLV_TYPE>(value.at(0));

    // Get tag name size.
    vector<uint8_t> tmp;
    tmp.push_back(value.at(1));
    tmp.push_back(value.at(2));
    uint16_t tagLength = LEToUINT16(tmp);

    if(tagLength > MAXTAGLENGTH)
        throw exception("Tag name length exceeded");

    // Now get tag name
    std::string tagName;
    for(int i = 0; i<tagLength; i++)
        tagName += value.at(3 + i); // Use an offset.

    if(tlvType == STRING)
    {

        // Get value size
        vector<uint8_t> tmp;
        tmp.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 0));
        tmp.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 1));
        tmp.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 2));
        tmp.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 3));
        uint32_t valueSize = LEToUINT32(tmp);

        clearMembers();

        // Get value
        m_strValue="";
        for(uint32_t i = 0; i<valueSize; i++)
            m_strValue += value.at(3 + tagLength + 4 + i);

        // Assign other values too if we got this far.
        m_tlvType = tlvType;
        m_tagName = tagName;
    }else if (tlvType == BLOB)
    {

        // Get value size
        vector<uint8_t> tmp;
        tmp.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 0));
        tmp.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 1));
        tmp.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 2));
        tmp.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 3));
        uint32_t valueSize = LEToUINT32(tmp);

        clearMembers();

        // Get value
        m_blob.clear();
        for(uint32_t i = 0; i<valueSize; i++)
            m_blob.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 4 + i));

        // Assign other values too if we got this far.
        m_tlvType = tlvType;
        m_tagName = tagName;
    }else if (tlvType == BYTE)
    {

        // Get value size
        vector<uint8_t> tmp;
        tmp.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 0));
        tmp.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 1));
        tmp.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 2));
        tmp.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 3));
        uint32_t valueSize = LEToUINT32(tmp);

        clearMembers();

        // Get value
        m_BYTE = value.at(3 + tagLength + 4);

        // Assign other values too if we got this far.
        m_tlvType = tlvType;
        m_tagName = tagName;

    } else if (tlvType == WORD)
    {

        // Get value size
        vector<uint8_t> tmp;
        tmp.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 0));
        tmp.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 1));
        tmp.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 2));
        tmp.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 3));
        uint32_t valueSize = LEToUINT32(tmp);



        // Get byte array represenginf the WORD
        vector<uint8_t> tmp2;
        for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
            tmp2.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 4 + i));

        clearMembers();


        // Store word
        m_WORD = LEToUINT16(tmp2);


        // Assign other values too if we got this far.
        m_tlvType = tlvType;
        m_tagName = tagName;
    }else if (tlvType == DWORD)
    {

        // Get value size
        vector<uint8_t> tmp;
        tmp.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 0));
        tmp.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 1));
        tmp.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 2));
        tmp.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 3));
        uint32_t valueSize = LEToUINT32(tmp);


        // Get byte array represenginf the WORD
        vector<uint8_t> tmp2;
        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
            tmp2.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 4 + i));

        clearMembers();


        // Store work
        m_DWORD = LEToUINT32(tmp2);


        // Assign other values too if we got this far.
        m_tlvType = tlvType;
        m_tagName = tagName;
    }else if (tlvType == QWORD)
    {

        // Get value size
        vector<uint8_t> tmp;
        tmp.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 0));
        tmp.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 1));
        tmp.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 2));
        tmp.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 3));
        uint32_t valueSize = LEToUINT32(tmp);


        // Get byte array represenginf the WORD
        vector<uint8_t> tmp2;
        for(int i = 0; i<8; i++)
            tmp2.push_back(value.at(3 + tagLength + 4 + i));

        clearMembers();

        // Store work
        m_QWORD = LEToUINT64(tmp2);


        // Assign other values too if we got this far.
        m_tlvType = tlvType;
        m_tagName = tagName;
    }
}
```

header:

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdint>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#define MAXTAGLENGTH 20000
using namespace std;

enum TLV_TYPE {UNDEFINED = 0, BYTE, WORD, DWORD, QWORD, STRING, BLOB};

class TLVObject
{
private:
    TLV_TYPE m_tlvType;    // TLV type
    std::string m_tagName; // TLV tag name; tag name max length is MAXTAGLENGTH

    // Possible TLV values:
    // TLV data size is 4 byte unsigned integer max.
    uint8_t m_BYTE;
    uint16_t m_WORD;
    uint32_t m_DWORD;
    uint64_t m_QWORD;
    string m_strValue;
    vector<uint8_t> m_blob;

    void clearMembers()
    {
        m_tlvType = UNDEFINED;
        m_tagName = "";

        m_BYTE = 0;
        m_WORD = 0;
        m_DWORD = 0;
        m_QWORD = 0;
        m_strValue = "";
    }

    // Helpers
    // These work exclusively assuming little endian encoding
    vector<uint8_t> UINT16ToByteArrayLE(uint16_t paramInt);
    vector<uint8_t> UINT32ToByteArrayLE(uint32_t paramInt);
    vector<uint8_t> UINT64ToByteArrayLE(uint64_t paramInt);
    uint16_t LEToUINT16(vector<uint8_t> value);
    uint32_t LEToUINT32(vector<uint8_t> value);
    uint64_t LEToUINT64(vector<uint8_t> value);


public:

    vector<uint8_t> Serialize();
    void  Deserialize(vector<uint8_t> value);



    TLVObject(string tag, vector<uint8_t> blob)
    {
        if(tag.length() > MAXTAGLENGTH)
            throw exception("Tag name length exceeded");

        m_tlvType = BLOB;
        m_tagName = tag;
        m_blob = blob;
    }

    TLVObject(string tag, uint8_t value)
    {
        if(tag.length() > MAXTAGLENGTH)
            throw exception("Tag name length exceeded");

        m_tlvType = BYTE;
        m_tagName = tag;
        m_BYTE = value;
    }

    TLVObject(string tag, uint16_t value)
    {
        if(tag.length() > MAXTAGLENGTH)
            throw exception("Tag name length exceeded");

        m_tlvType = WORD;
        m_tagName = tag;
        m_WORD = value;
    }

    TLVObject(string tag, uint32_t value)
    {
        if(tag.length() > MAXTAGLENGTH)
            throw exception("Tag name length exceeded");

        m_tlvType = DWORD;
        m_tagName = tag;
        m_DWORD = value;
    }

    TLVObject(string tag, uint64_t value)
    {
        if(tag.length() > MAXTAGLENGTH)
            throw exception("Tag name length exceeded");

        m_tlvType = QWORD;
        m_tagName = tag;
        m_QWORD = value;
    }

    TLVObject(string tag, string value)
    {
        if(tag.length() > MAXTAGLENGTH)
            throw exception("Tag name length exceeded");

        m_tlvType = STRING;
        m_tagName = tag;
        m_strValue = value;
    }

    string GetStringValue()
    {
        if(m_tlvType != STRING)
            throw exception("This is not string TLV");

        return m_strValue;

    }

    vector<uint8_t> GetBlobValue()
    {

        if(m_tlvType != BLOB)
            throw exception("This is not BLOB TLV");

        return m_blob;
    }

    uint8_t GetBYTEValue()
    {
        if(m_tlvType != BYTE)
            throw exception("This is not BYTE TLV");

        return m_BYTE;
    }

    uint16_t GetUINT16Value()
    {
        if(m_tlvType != WORD)
            throw exception("This is not WORD TLV");

        return m_WORD;
    }

    uint32_t GetUINT32Value()
    {
        if(m_tlvType != DWORD)
            throw exception("This is not DWORD TLV");

        return m_DWORD;
    }

    uint64_t GetUINT64Value()
    {
        if(m_tlvType != QWORD)
            throw exception("This is not QWORD TLV");

        return m_QWORD;
    }

    TLV_TYPE GetType()
    {
        return m_tlvType;
    }

    TLVObject(void);
    ~TLVObject(void);
};
```

Test program for single TLV

```
  TLVObject obj("Name", (uint16_t)255);
  vector<uint8_t> tmp = obj.Serialize(); // Serialize as byte array


  TLVObject obj1;
  obj1.Deserialize(tmp); // Reconstruct TLV from byte array
```

Answer (score 5):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your code.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.  It is particularly bad to put it into a header file, so please don't do that.  Instead, simply specify the namespace where you use it, so `cout` becomes `std::cout`, `endl` becomes `std::endl` and so forth.

### Use all required `#include`s

The code uses `std::string` and appears to use`std::exception` but doesn't include the corresponding headers.  The code should have:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
```

And not

```
#include <string.h>
```

While the code may compile as you have it, it's solely due to the implementation details of the particular compiler and library you are using.  It can't be relied on and can (and does) change from version to version of even a single compiler on a single platform.  You can use a reference such as http://en.cppreference.com to make sure you know which standard header to include for each standard function.

### Use polymorphism

The current design has each `TLVObject` having one of each possible interpretation embedded within it.  A more C++-style design would be to have a single base class and then derive the particular types from that base class.  So for example, you might still have `TLVObject` as the base class, but then derive `TLVByte`, `TLVWord`, etc. from that.  Not only would that make the interface cleaner, but it would simplify adding new types.

### Consider ASN.1

There is a [standard called ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) that already describes ways of encoding many of these types.  Instead of re-inventing your own tags, you may find it useful to use the ones defined by ASN.1.

### Use const where practical

Methods that do not modify the underlying object, should be declared `const`:

### Pass by const reference

Several places in the code, such as `TLVObject::LEToUINT64(vector<uint8_t> value)` take their parameters by value.  Instead, they could likely be made more efficient by passing a `const` reference, as in:

```
TLVObject::LEToUINT64(const vector<uint8_t> &value)
```

This avoids copying into a new vector and signals the compiler that the passed value will not be altered.

### Simplify the code

There are some overly complex pieces of code in this.  For example, we have this:

```
// Get tag name size.
vector<uint8_t> tmp;
tmp.push_back(value.at(1));
tmp.push_back(value.at(2));
uint16_t tagLength = LEToUINT16(tmp);
```

That would be shorter, faster, and more portable if written like this instead:

```
uint16_t tagLength = value.at(2) << 8 | value.at(1);
```

Creating the temporary vector, passing it by value and then destroying both copies means two constructor and two destructor calls which are wholly unnecessary and only slows down the code.

**About type conversions**: Note that the arithmetic operators (including `<<` and `|`) don't operate on integral values smaller than `int`. What happens is automatic type conversion to either `int` or `unsigned` so no explicit cast is necessary.

### Prefer `constexpr` to old-style `#define`

Rather than using a `#define` for `MAXTAGLENGTH` the code could use a `constexpr`:

```
constexpr std::size_t MAXTAGLENGTH = 20000;
```

It doesn't make a lot of difference here, but generally the advantage is that the value has an associated type.

### Eliminate unused variables

The `valueSize` variable in `Deserialize` is not used.  That's quite strange considering the number of lines of code dedicated to extracting it.

Comment: Yeah with numeric values I know the valueSize and that's why, but no need to parse it then. PS Polymorphism advice I find unnecessary really. Thanks. I will look at these points once again later

Comment: "(value.at(2) << 8)" is it ok to shift uint8_t with 8 bits?. Also how to solve namespace issue then?

Comment: Yes, I've amended my answer to talk about type conversion. I'm not sure what you mean when you ask about solving a "namespace issue."

Comment: I don't think we should drop ```const``` while using constexpr. They actually have different semantics. ```constexpr const std::size_t MAXTAGLENGTH = 20000;```

Comment: @AntiMoron: no, constexpr implies const in this context. There is no reason to have both here.

Comment: @Edward I meant if I don't use `using namespace std` - what to use? Also why I didn't get warning with headers, and what happens if I don't include those headers?

Comment: I've added to my answer to address those issues.