# Polymorphic TLV serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, c++14, factory-method, polymorphism

Inspired by [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115395/tlv-implementation-in-c) I decided to write an alternative that uses polymorhphism and a Factory pattern.  The code works for the subset of implemented types, namely `BYTE`, `WORD` and `STRING` but I have a few concerns:

1. I'd like to get rid of the big ugly switch in the `TLVFactory`.
2. Is there a way to make the `TLVFactory::create` a static member of `TLVObject`?
3. Any other code improvement suggests, perhaps regarding casts.

### tlv2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>

class TLVObject
{
public:
    enum TLV_TYPE {UNDEFINED = 0, BYTE, WORD, DWORD, QWORD, STRING, BLOB};
    TLVObject(TLV_TYPE type) :
        m_type{type}
    {}
    virtual ~TLVObject() {}
    virtual size_t len() const { return 0; }
    virtual std::ostream &write(std::ostream &out) const { 
        writeTag(out);
        writeLen(out);
        writeData(out);
        return out;
    }
    virtual std::ostream &writeTag(std::ostream &out) const { 
        return out.put(m_type); 
    }
    virtual std::ostream &writeLen(std::ostream &out) const {
        return out.put(len());
    }
    virtual std::ostream &writeData(std::ostream &out) const {
        return out;
    }
    virtual std::istream &read(std::istream &in) {
        readTag(in);
        readLen(in);
        readData(in);
        return in;
    }
    virtual std::istream &readTag(std::istream &in) { 
        char ch;
        in.get(ch);
        m_type = static_cast<TLV_TYPE>(ch);
        return in;
    }
    virtual std::istream &readLen(std::istream &in) { return in; }
    virtual std::istream &readData(std::istream &in) { return in; }
private:
    TLV_TYPE m_type;
};

class TLVByte : public TLVObject
{
public:
    TLVByte(uint8_t value) :
        TLVObject{BYTE},
        m_value{value}
    {}
    TLVByte() : TLVByte{0} {}
    virtual ~TLVByte() {}
    virtual size_t len() const { return sizeof(m_value); }
    virtual std::ostream &writeData(std::ostream &out) const { 
        return out.put(m_value); 
    }
    virtual std::istream &readLen(std::istream &in) {
        if (len() != static_cast<size_t>(in.get())) {
            std::out_of_range("TLV len error");
        } 
        return in;
    }
    virtual std::istream &readData(std::istream &in) { 
        m_value = in.get(); return in; 
    }
private:
    uint8_t m_value;
};

class TLVWord : public TLVObject
{
    public:
    TLVWord(uint16_t value) :
        TLVObject{WORD},
        m_value{value}
    {}
    TLVWord() : TLVWord{0} {}
    virtual ~TLVWord() {}
    virtual size_t len() const { return sizeof(m_value); }
    virtual std::ostream &writeData(std::ostream &out) const { 
        return out.put(m_value >> 8).put(m_value & 0xff);
    }
    virtual std::istream &readLen(std::istream &in) {
        if (len() != static_cast<size_t>(in.get())) {
            std::out_of_range("TLV len error");
        } 
        return in;
    }
    virtual std::istream &readData(std::istream &in) { 
        m_value = in.get() << 8; 
        m_value |= in.get();
        return in; 
    }
private:
    uint16_t m_value;
};


class TLVString : public TLVObject
{
public:
    TLVString(std::string str) :
        TLVObject{STRING},
        m_value{str}
    {}
    TLVString() : TLVString("") {}
    virtual ~TLVString() {}
    virtual size_t len() const { return m_value.size(); }
    virtual std::ostream &writeData(std::ostream &out) const { 
        return out << m_value;
    }
    virtual std::istream &readLen(std::istream &in) {
        m_value.reserve(in.get());
        return in;
    }
    virtual std::istream &readData(std::istream &in) { 
        for (int i = m_value.capacity(); i; --i) {
            m_value += in.get();
        }
        return in; 
    }
private:
    std::string m_value;
};

class TLVFactory
{
public:
    static std::unique_ptr<TLVObject> create(TLVObject::TLV_TYPE type) {
        switch (type) {
            case TLVObject::BYTE: 
                return std::make_unique<TLVByte>();
                break;
            case TLVObject::WORD: 
                return std::make_unique<TLVWord>();
                break;
            case TLVObject::STRING: 
                return std::make_unique<TLVString>();
                break;
            case TLVObject::DWORD: 
            case TLVObject::QWORD: 
            case TLVObject::BLOB:
            default:
                std::out_of_range("Can't construct object of that type");
        }
        return std::make_unique<TLVObject>(TLVObject::UNDEFINED);
    }
};

class TLVCollection : public std::vector<std::unique_ptr<TLVObject>> {
public:
    void write(std::ostream &out) const {
        for (const auto &item : *this) {
            item->write(out);
        }
    }
    void read(std::istream &in) {
        while (in.good() && in.peek() > 0) {
            push_back(TLVFactory::create(static_cast<TLVObject::TLV_TYPE>(in.peek())));
            back()->read(in);
        }
    }
};
```

### Simple test code

```
int main()
{
    TLVCollection vec;
    vec.push_back(std::make_unique<TLVByte>(TLVByte{7}));
    vec.push_back(std::make_unique<TLVString>(TLVString{"banana"}));
    vec.push_back(std::make_unique<TLVWord>(TLVWord{0x1234}));
    std::ofstream out("tlvtest.bin");
    vec.write(out);
    out.close();

    TLVCollection v2;
    std::ifstream in("tlvtest.bin");
    v2.read(in);
    in.close();
    v2.write(std::cout);
}
```

## Results

When I run the program and pipe its output through `xxd` which simply converts the binary input to a hexadecimal representation, I get this:

> ```
> ./tlv2 |xxd
> 00000000: 0101 0705 0662 616e 616e 6102 0212 34    .....banana...4
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few suggestions.

## Use `const` where appropriate

In your constructors you simply copy the passed-in value without mutating it. It should be declared `const` since it's not mutated.

## Don't allow invalid objects to be constructed

I don't understand the point of allowing a caller to create an undefined TLV type. It has 0 length, so there's nothing to write or read. It would be better to simply not allow such a thing to even be constructed. I'd remove the `UNDEFINED` value from the enum. (It might be worth it to make the constructor for the base class protected so it can't be directly instantiated outside of a subclass.)

## Use pure virtual methods where appropriate

If `TLVObject` made `virtual` the methods which must be overridden by subclasses, the compiler will stop a caller from constructing the base object. So I'd make `len()`, `writeData()`, `readLen()`, and `readData()` all pure virtual:

```
virtual size_t len() const = 0;
...
virtual std::ostream &writeData(std::ostream &out) const = 0;
...
virtual std::istream &readLen(std::istream &in) = 0;
virtual std::istream &readData(std::istream &in) = 0;
```

## Use `override` on overridden methods

When you override a method in a subclass, you should mark it as `override` so the compiler knows your intent and will warn you if the method signature ever changes in the base class or if you spell it wrong in a subclass. So it would look like this:

```
class TLVByte : public TLVObject
{
...
    virtual size_t len() const override { return sizeof(m_value); }
    virtual std::ostream &writeData(std::ostream &out) const override { 
        return out.put(m_value); 
    }
    virtual std::istream &readLen(std::istream &in) override {
        if (len() != static_cast<size_t>(in.get())) {
            std::out_of_range("TLV len error");
        } 
        return in;
    }
    virtual std::istream &readData(std::istream &in) override { 
        m_value = in.get(); return in; 
    }
```

...

## Factory method

Overall your factory method looks completely reasonable. I originally though, "There's no reason it couldn't be a public static method inside of `TLVObject`. You'd simply need to forward declare the subclasses":

```
class TLVByte;
class TLVWord;
class TLVString;

class TLVObject
{
public:
    enum TLV_TYPE {UNDEFINED = 0, BYTE, WORD, DWORD, QWORD, STRING, BLOB};
    static std::unique_ptr<TLVObject> create(TLVObject::TLV_TYPE type) {
        switch (type) {
            case TLVObject::BYTE: 
                return std::make_unique<TLVByte>();
                break;
            case TLVObject::WORD: 
                return std::make_unique<TLVWord>();
                break;
            case TLVObject::STRING: 
                return std::make_unique<TLVString>();
                break;
            case TLVObject::DWORD: 
            case TLVObject::QWORD: 
            case TLVObject::BLOB:
            default:
                std::out_of_range("Can't construct object of that type");
        }
        return std::make_unique<TLVObject>(TLVObject::UNDEFINED);
    }
...
```

However, I was wrong. The above won't work because you're trying to use a not-yet fully described type as the argument to a template (`std::unique_ptr<T>`), and that's not going to work.

Another option is to make it a free-standing function. There's no reason it needs to be in a class by itself, though there's no problem with doing it that way.

As you probably guessed from the above mistake, I'm no expert at templates. So a question - would it be possible to do something like make the `create()` method a templated function? Something like:

```
template<T>
static unique_ptr<T> create()
{
    return std::make_unique<T>();
}
```

Or even just get rid of the factory function and create them just using `std::make_unqiue<Whichever>();`?

Also, the last return statement for your `create()` will never be reached since you have a `default` `case`. And as mentioned above, it shouldn't be necessary because you shouldn't allow construction of an undefined object.

Comment: On the last point, are you actually able to compile it that way? Using `gcc` I get errors that I am unable to resolve.

Comment: Ah, interesting. No, I hadn't compiled it, and trying to do so, I can't. It looks like the templating system needs the full type to make one. I'll update the answer.